# Div: Percentage width but does not resize with parent

Tags: html, css

So I have a container

```
   #container{
     width: 1000px;
   }
```

And an item (div)

```
   #item{
     width: 65%;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

Then I put item into the container

```
   <div id="container">
     <div id="item"></div>
   </div>
```

When I resize the browser, container is the out most div, so it is resized. But so is "item".
If I put **width: 650px;** instead of **width: 65%**, I get what I need: the item will not be resized as I resize the browser.
Problem is I want to keep it as a percentage.

I need the item NOT to be resized when the browser is being resized, and the item must have a fixed px value. How could I do this?

What I do NOT want
[image: 1]

What I want
[image: 1]

Comment: Can you set the container width to 100%..?

Comment: Just replace your `item` css by `position: relative; display: block; width: 65%; margin: auto;`

Comment: @Nadeeth yes, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks, but it does not work.

Comment: @ares94 Can't see an issue http://plnkr.co/edit/iIUjtt?p=preview

Comment: Well, use this css for `#container`     `max-width: 1000px; width: 100%;` and also you must set height for both divs

Comment: @PSL Thanks for that, but if you run it in a separate window, you will see it.

Comment: @ares94 I could see it shrinking as you reduce the browser window.. Probably i did not get what your issue is

Comment: @Ahmad, I tried your method on this link: [link](http://run.plnkr.co/SAJXRHrSEuSHev69/)

Comment: It's working fine !!! Can you make screenshot

Comment: You have got it wrong. **container** does **not** resize. You just don't see the hidden part when you resize the window. You can double check this by adding a background colour to the body. Then you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed px value then go ahead and use the 650px. Percentages are used to be dynamic, from the term it self 'Percentage' the RATIO, not a specific dimension, is maintained.